# C, How to malloc the correct amount of space for an array of a struct inside another struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have two structs. I am trying the make an array of 'struct bird' inside another struct 'struct nest'.

I am having a hard time allocating the correct amount of space for the bird array when I am creating the nest struct.

Below is my code.

```
struct bird {
  int value;
};
typedef struct bird bird;

struct nest {
  int nb_birds;
  bird * * birds;     //bird * = points to the bird struct, * birds = Array with size unknown
};
typedef struct nest nest;

nest * create_nest(int nb_birds) {
  nest * n = (nest *) malloc(sizeof(nest));
  n->nb_birds = nb_birds;

   //This is where I am stuck
  ***n->birds = (bird *) malloc(sizeof(bird) * nb_birds);*** 


  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < nb_birds; i++)
    n->birds[i]=NULL;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the prototype and/or function declaration of that snippet of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to allocate array of `nb_birds` *pointers* to `bird` structure, so size to allocation is `nb_birds * sizeof(bird *)`.

Then you want to store pointer to this array, so cast should be to address of the first element — address of `bird *`, i.e. `bird **`.

Hence,

```
n->birds = (bird **) malloc(sizeof(bird *) * nb_birds);
```

p.s. If you want to allocate `N` objects on which `ptr` points to, you can write, or, at least, think about as

```
ptr = (typeof(ptr)) malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * N);
```

**Update:**

It *should be* noted that `malloc` returns `void *` pointer that compatible with any pointer type without explicit casting. So, quoted program line can be as short as

```
ptr = malloc(N * sizeof(*ptr));
```

Some programmers, despite them well informed about this `void *` property, strongly prefer to use explicit cast in such cases. I'm not one of them, but  I account such casts as stylistіc preference (like `()` for `sizeof` operator). So I left the casting in code above because OP use it, and I thought it was his choice.

Neverthless it is needed (at least for answer completeness and for further readers) to note that such cast is ***unnecessary** and **excessive***.
.

<sub>*Thank you **Paul Ogilvie** and **chux** for patient notes in the comments.*</sub>

Comment: ..and don't cast the result of `malloc`. It returns `void *` which is compatible with any pointer type. `n->birds = malloc(sizeof(bird *) * nb_birds);` is all the answer requires.

Comment: Agree, casting of `void *` returned by malloc is redundant (and I never use it). But some programmers prefer to explicit cast and I left this part of code as is. Anyway, your comment is very useful.

Comment: `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N);` is even easier to code right, review and maintain.  No "type" needed as in `n->birds = malloc(sizeof *(n->birds) * nb_birds);`

Comment: @chux Your comment is the same as one of Paul Ogilvie above. But I added note because it is hot topic :-). Thanks for help in war with my lazyness.